# Different Payment Method based on billing Country

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods, billing-address

I am migrating an e-commerce site to Magento.

I need to use different payment methods depending on the billing country.

Default site currency is USD. Any orders with a non-Canadian billing address use Authorize.net for CC payment.

If the billing address is Canadian, the site will use Paypal Payments Pro for Visa/MC and Authorize.net for Amex and will be billed in CAD.

From my research, it seems that I'm going to have to use 2 Stores (which seems less than ideal to me). Can anyone provide some experienced feedback on how to configure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

In the case where you need to provide an alternative payment method, I would literally change the Payment Labels in the backend to reflect that certain methods are for specific countries.

**However** there *is* the facility in Magento 1.8+ that allows you to relegate specific billing methods to specific countries. Under "Advanced Settings" for Paypal Payments Pro:

[image]

And here for Authorize:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer philwinkle! Your suggestion is exactly what I've done for the time being. It's not perfect, but it gets us out the door until I get a little further down the path to Magento Mastery!

Comment: This answer solves half of the problem. The remainder of the problem is identified in this question: [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35448/switch-currency-on-billing-country-selection)