# switch currency on billing country selection

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

My site is setup with USD as the base currency. I am using different payment methods based on countries however I need to have the currency for the transaction processed in CAD (Canadian Dollars) if the users billing address is in Canada.

The best I can tell, I need to add a custom event observer to accomplish this but that's a little more advanced than I'm prepared for. Can anybody provide some direction or alternative solutions? The modules I've seen out there that can accomplish this seem to use GeoIP instead of being based off of a billing address field and this isn't sufficient for our use case.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

you need trigger event      `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling` on  on `billing address  saveBillingAction`;

and the below code at observer set current currency as Canadian if country is Canada

```
$controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
 $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
/*
$result = array();
$result['error'] = '-1';
$result['message'] = 'YOUR MESSAGE HERE';
$controllerAction->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result))
*/
if($data['country_id']=='canadacode' && Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()='CanadaCurrencyCod'){

 Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($curency);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the directions Amit. Due to my inexperience, this will take me a little while to prove out correctly. Once I have, I will approve the answer.